# how to create a list from a dataframe using conditions

Tags: r, list, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
R:
    X       Y       Z       L
                .
                .
                .
    a       2       8       0
    b       3       2       0
    c       12      5       0 
    d       3       22      0
    e       4       33      0
    f       2       1       1
    g       3       4       0
    h       1       2       0
    i       2       5       0 
    j       7       4       0
    k       3       3       1
    ...
```

if N is the number of times that L > 0, how can i create a list() of N objects which consist on this way:

If i is the row where L>0 the first object would have row among i-3 and i from dataframe R, and this for all the i rows where L>0, like this:

```
list()
[1]
    d       3       22      0
    e       4       33      0
    f       2       1       1
[2]
    i       2       5       0 
    j       7       4       0
    k       3       3       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and that R can't do something like L[5] = 1 and L[6] = 1, then how about:

```
ind = which(R[, "L"] > 0)
res = vector(mode = "list", length = length(ind))
for (iind in seq_along(ind)) {
   res[[iind]] = R[(ind[iind]-2):ind[iind],]
}
```

I subtracted `i-2` because your output has 3 rows.  If `R` is a matrix, then the results in the list `res` will be matrices.  You can wrap `as.data.frame()` around that subsetting operation to get `data.frame`s if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, except for the two first lines of your dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(X=letters, Y=rnorm(26,0,1),L=rbinom(26,1,0.5))
df


List<-list()
for (i in 3:length(df$X)) {
  if (df$L[i] == 1) {
    a <- df[(i-2):i,]
  } else { a<-NULL 
    }

  List[[length(List)+1]] = a

}


List
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without for-loop.

Step 1: Set `i` to be 3

Step 2: Subset the data frame `dat` to have the right rows

Step 3: Create a grouping variable `Group` based on number of rows and `i`

Step 4: Split the data frame based on `Group`

Step 5: Remove the `Group` column for each subset

```
i <- 3    
dat2 <- dat[as.vector(sapply(which(dat$L == 1), function(x) x + seq(-i + 1, 0))), ]
dat2$Group <- rep(1:(nrow(dat2)/i), each = i)
dat_list <- split(dat2, dat2$Group)
dat_list <- lapply(dat_list, function(x){
  x$Group <- NULL
  return(x)})
```

Here is the result

```
dat_list
# $`1`
#   X Y  Z L
# 4 d 3 22 0
# 5 e 4 33 0
# 6 f 2  1 1
# 
# $`2`
#    X Y Z L
# 9  i 2 5 0
# 10 j 7 4 0
# 11 k 3 3 1
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "    X       Y       Z       L
    a       2       8       0
    b       3       2       0
    c       12      5       0 
    d       3       22      0
    e       4       33      0
    f       2       1       1
    g       3       4       0
    h       1       2       0
    i       2       5       0 
    j       7       4       0
    k       3       3       1", 
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```